# multi language site PHP ,illegal offset string

Tags: php, html

Hello i am facing a problem which is really confusing me when I want to print the strings stored in the array . I have

Warning: Illegal string offset 'TITLE' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\index.php on line 443
...
Actually the site is multi language and i want to display diffenet languages upon the desire of the user. What is the origin of this problem ?

```html
<?php
include_once 'common.php';
?>

<form method="get"  name="signup" >
 <h1 id="head"></head></br>
 <h1 ><?php echo $lang['USER_REGISTRATION']; ?></h1>
 <h4 id="req">*Donates Required Fields</h4>
<table>

 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $lang['TITLE']; ?>:*</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}

else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}

else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;


  case 'pr':
  $lang_file = 'lang.pr.php';
  break;

   case 'ar':
  $lang_file = 'lang.ar.php';
  break;
  
  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

}

include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

```html
$lang['USER_REGISTRATION']="User Registration";
$lang['TITLE']="Title";
```

Comment: `$lang['USER_REGISTRATION']="User Registration";
$lang['TITLE']="Title";` is this your common.php?

Comment: @PrashantTapase No I think its his `include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;`

Comment: Are you sure that the language file thats getting loaded by `include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;` actually exists?

Comment: name your file and write code in flow so that we can find out what is your problem.

Comment: **Take a close look at what `$lang` is exactly!** It's a string, not an array.

Comment: He also defined it as a array @deceze. But it is unclear when he did what, through his files.

Comment: @Nytrix Since the error message clearly says *"string offset"*, it's a string.

Comment: @PrashantTapase yes it is include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file,

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `$lang` does not have the `key` and `value` of `TITLE`. To check what keys and values an array has use `var_dump()`. You need to define `$lang['TITLE']` before echo'ing.

Comment: you mean var_dump($lang )?

Comment: Yes. You will basically see that the array does not have the key `TITLE`. You need define that first. Then you can echo it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly says, `$lang` is a string, not an array. Total shot in the dark here:

**Your `include_once` is not including the file,** because you've already included it elsewhere and it's not being included a second time due to the `_once`. That, or that file does not exist, in which case you need to check your error logs.

Comment: Yes, the `$lang` variable is a string, but a string can be treated as an **indexed array** and the error says that the `string offset` is illegal because, even if PHP does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays, a string can't be treated as an **associative array**, therefore PHP says that you can't search an array element with a string key in a `string` variable.

Comment: Well, yes, exactly. OP has the expectation that `$lang` is an array, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: I just want to point out what _"string offset"_ means. In [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31723602/#comment51385067_31723602), in short, you say that _"string offset"_ refers to the datatype but it refers to the offset `["TITLE"]` and not to the datatype. **1)** `$array[3] // Legal offset` **2)** `$array["TITLE"] // Legal offset (if the "TITLE" key is not set, PHP throws a "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 'TITLE'")` **3)** `$string[0] // Legal offset` **4)** `$string["TITLE"] // Illegal offset, a PHP string can't be treated as an associative array`

Comment: I refer to the fact that the type of `$lang` is not, as expected, an array, but a string. The datatype of `$lang` is wrong for the expected operation. This produces that particular error message, yes. That error message is an indicator of the underlying problem: `$lang` is not what the OP thinks it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$language='ru';
if ($language=='ru') {
    $lang['Add']='Добавить';
    $lang['Back']='Назад';
    $lang['Cancel']='Отмена';
    $lang['Date']='Дата';
    $lang['Days']='Дней';
    $lang['Upload']='Загрузить';
    $lang['Value']='Значение';
    $lang['Hello']='Привет';
}
/* Functions */
//translation
function __($text){
    global $lang;
    if (isset($lang[$text])){ return $lang[$text];}
    else {return $text;}
};

echo __('Add');
```